# How to make the version check not a warning but an error?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode when version of main target and extension mismatch I receive next `warning`

```bash
The CFBundleShortVersionString of an app extension ('1.0') must match that of its containing parent app ('1.1').
```

How convert warning to error?

I mark main target and extension targets

```bash
SWIFT_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS = YES;
```

Try set `WARNING_CFLAGS` but all this did not lead to success